# Manually setting colours for Voronio plot when colouring by factor using ggvoronoi

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, voronoi

Morning, afternoon
or evening.

```
# Reproducible data
df <- quakes[1:20, 1:2]
df$years <-  as.factor(rep(c("2000","2020"), each=10))
df$cluster <- as.factor(c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2",
                          "2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3"))
```

I am using GPS data to create voronoi plots and colouring them by a factor (output of k-means clustering). I need to create quite a few plots so I am running it in a loop, as follows:

```
years <- levels(df$years)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvoronoi)

for(i in years){
  #
  single_year <- df %>% 
    filter(years == i)
  #
  #
  plot <- ggplot(single_year,
                 aes(x=lat,
                     y=long)) +
    #
    geom_voronoi(aes(fill=(cluster))) +
    #
    stat_voronoi(geom="path" )+
    #
    geom_point() +
    #
    labs(title = paste(i))
  #
  #
  ggsave(paste0(i,".jpeg"), plot = last_plot(), # Watch out for the SAVE!!!
         device = 'jpeg')
  #
}
```

This gives me the following (awesome) plots: 
[image]

This issue is in the colour. I want to have consistency between plots. For example, for ever plot the cluster 2 would be blue, cluster 3 = red, etc.

I am confused which of the many ggplot colour options to use here to ensure consistency. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a vector to attribute a color to each values of "cluster" variable and then pass them into the argument `values =` of the `scale_fill_manual` function as in the following :

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggvoronoi)
library(dplyr)
for(i in df$years){
  #
  col  = c("1" = "green", "2" = "blue", "3" = "red")
  single_year <- df %>% 
    filter(years == i)
  #
  #
  plot <- ggplot(single_year,
                 aes(x=lat,
                     y=long)) +
    #
    geom_voronoi(aes(fill = cluster)) +
    #
    stat_voronoi(geom="path" )+
    #
    geom_point() +
    #
    labs(title = paste(i))+
    scale_fill_manual(values = col)
  #
  #
  ggsave(paste0(i,".jpeg"), plot = last_plot(), # Watch out for the SAVE!!!
         device = 'jpeg')
  #
}
```

[image]
and
[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: worked a treat. Many thanks. I do so often confuse myself with ggplot colour options.

Comment: You're welcome ;) Don't worry you are not the only one ;)